# How to display JOptionPane dialogbox of different instances?

Tags: java, joptionpane

I created different instances of JOptionPane in the if clause as shown as below :

```
JOptionPane myInstance ;
if(someCondition is true){
     myInstance = new JOptionPane(ErrorMessage,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
else{
    myInstance = new JOptionPane(InformationMessage,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

Now how to display those instance of JOptionPane??
I tried this:

```
myInstance.setVisible(true)
```

but it didn't work for me.
How to display these instances???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it in this way:

```
JOptionPane myInstance ;
if(someCondition is true){
     myInstance = new JOptionPane(ErrorMessage,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
else{
    myInstance = new JOptionPane(InformationMessage,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}

JDialog dialog = myInstance.createDialog(parentComponent/* null for new window*/, title);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: [Dialog.show() is deprecated.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#show--)  Use [setVisible(true)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setVisible-boolean-) instead.

Comment: What is meant by the term "deprecated"?? I have read this term in many documents . But have not understood..